# Export parameters from one app to other ios

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, data-transfer, custom-url

I want to transfer some parameters from my app to 3tr party app.
For example from "My app" to f.e. "Uber". ("Uber" company known about about this and they wait for this data).

If app installed, I can use deep links:

```
 let sharedApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
 sharedApplication.openURL(NSURL(string: "uber//:params_in_JSON_format")!)
```

But if this app didn't install, "My app" open App store, and user can install it. After lunching 3rt party app, it must get that parameters what I just sand from "My app".

I reviewed sites, and tried customize it for my requirements, but they don't provide such functionality. Sites: https://branch.io/, https://www.appsflyer.com/, and some other.

Have you any idea how to do this?

Comment: Branch.IO did that for us. With Branch.IO you can programatically add meta data to the deep link, and it passes through the AppStore install. However, The 3rd party will also have to use Branch.IO. In addition, we had to use the new "Universal link" standard, and not the old "URI Schema" standard that you use in your example.

Comment: @ArikSegal, yes I know that 3rt party app should integrated Branch.IO, it is not a problem. If I will use "Universal link" will I get parameters after app installation?

Comment: @vn_serg Alex with Branch.io here: yes, you *do* get parameters after app installation. See our [docs page about Universal Links](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/overview/) for info on how it works!

Comment: It worked for us. Just follow the instruction they give about creating links and accessing the data from the links. The Branch handler that is invoked when the app is launched DOES show all the link's data, even if the app wasn't yet installed when the link was tapped. Might also work without the Universal Link thing, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @AlexBauer I have prepared link from dashboard and open it from mail client - woks ok. But how I can create the same link with parameters (what will be changes) from app1 and sand it to app2? I review https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links-in-apps/overview/ but it doesn't help.

Comment: @vn_serg does the destination app ('Uber') have Branch integrated already, or would they be open to doing so?